# Charts not rendering ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Please help. I am trying to put charts on a aspx page but they don't show when attempting to view in browser. It just shows blank where the charts should be. Here is the aspx code. Thank you.

```
<h2>Top 5 Most Expensive Products</h2>
<br />
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 5 [price], [productName] FROM [products] ORDER BY [price] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
<h2>Total Number of Customers Per State</h2>
<br />
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the mapping between the **Data** coming from you **Database** and the `Series` in the `Charts`.

For that you need to use `XValueMember` and `YValueMember` to complete the mapping.

Try something like this:

```
<Series>
   <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" XValueMember="price" YValueMember="productName"></asp:Series>
</Series>
```

Comment: Thanks Ted! That did it.

Comment: @martinbshp - no problem. glad to have helped